El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especifico Visual Studio

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente al bajar los cambios desde mi repositorio y al querer ejecutar mi proyecto intenté seguir el paso de Limpiar Solucion > Compilar y Recompilar Solucion pero no funcionó.
Tambien intenté cargardo la carpeta bin desde una carpeta de ese mismo proyecto pero aun así no toma los cambios actuales que hay.

Tienes un error de compilacion, por esa razon no vas a poder ejecutar
Si puede ver o pasarnos cual es el error (seguramente ahi mas arriba te informa en el "output"/"salida" del build.
O sea primero verificar que se compila correctamente para poder ejecutar.
Con esto te podriamos ayudar mejor o extender tu pregunta con mas informacion de este "error de build"

